# Vue does not get template ref of vNode-rendered elements array with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating a library and I do renderless components that just renders whatever is in slots. For the purpose of demonstration, I added dummy VNodes array instead.

```
<template>
    <component
      v-for="vnode of vnodes"
      :key="vnode.toString()"
      :is="vnode"
      ref="elements"
    />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, h, onMounted } from "vue";

const elements = ref([]);

const vnodes = [
  h(
    "div",
    {
      class: "foo"
    },
    "Hello One!"
  ),
  h(
    "div",
    {
      class: "bar"
    },
    "Hello Two!"
  )
];

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(elements.value[0]); 
// expected: First element of array (Element)
// reality: undefined
});
</script>
```

[CodePen repro](https://codepen.io/jojk0/pen/NWXVerz)

In my use case, I fetch VNodes from slots and then rendering it via `<component>` in template. It renders properly, however I can't get the references to rendered elements at `onMounted()`. Does anyone know what's wrong with this approach, or is it a Vue bug?

Comment: what version of vue are you using?

Comment: It's Vue 3.2.31

Comment: So I've tried exactly the code you provided in exactly the version you mentioned and it works just fine (I used https://sfc.vuejs.org/ for testing it). Are you sure the error is not due to the fetch of the nodes?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying it in SFC vuejs and it's working. Weirdly, in CodePen it's not (they are using the latest one, 3.2.31)

Comment: Did the provided answer help? or are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: It works, thanks - it was a bug that has been fixed after update of Vue, my bad :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it in codepen and I also think this is how you should do it in vue 3. (best practice as of Vue.js version 3)

[Functional Template Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs)

```
:ref="(el) => elements.push(el)"
```

instead of

```
ref="elements"
```

If you face issues with duplicates in the array you might have to reset the array in a [vue lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html)

Comment: This will create duplicate elements on each update cycle.

Comment: @MartinZeltin as stated in the last part of sentence, you have to reset the array in a lifecycle hook.

Comment: If you have a unique id or index available you can also do this to avoid duplication `:ref="(el) => myElements[id] = el"`

Comment: @MartinZeltin you could edit my answer so it's included and I'm not pretending it is my answer (or my edit) :D